# Looping through array of objects within multiple objects and accessing values in D3 using underscore

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, d3.js, underscore.js

In ***`D3d.js`***, I'm trying to append rectangles for each object in the array, so the height of the rectangle is determined by the value. Also, I'm trying to make it so only the first object in each array shows first, and then when you **click a button** it cycles through the ***2nd*** and ***3rd*** `object`.

However I'm having issues looping through the data because not sure how to do it with this `JSON` structure--

```
  var data= {
    "Object_one":[
        {"date":"1/4/2010",
         "value":"50",},
        {"date":"6/22/2010",
         "value":"44",},
        {"date":"9/18/2010",
         "value":"42",},
    ],
    "Object_two":[
        {"date":"1/4/2010",
         "value":"54",},
        {"date":"6/22/2010",
         "value":"41",},
        {"date":"2012",
         "value":"42",},
    ],
    "Object_three":[
        {"date":"1/4/2010",
         "value":"55",},
        {"date":"6/22/2010",
         "value":"43",},
        {"date":"9/18/2010",
         "value":"65",},
    ]
}
```

I have a loop set up using `underscore.js` to loop through the data, but it's only taking in all the objects of the first array, as opposed to the first object in each `array` for each ***Object X***.

https://jsfiddle.net/vw88/6Ljekv45/

**(see line 55 of the js for the part that appends the rectangles with values)**

Comment: What is the structure goal ? Could you provide an example of what you expect ?

Comment: Thanks for replying, I'll post another fiddle shortly to show how it should look visually

Comment: That's not what I meant, I wanted to know what exactly you need to do with this data. I have never used d3.js, so you need to tell me if you want to change your data structure, or make some function calls.

Comment: I need to make function calls with the existing data structure. I've just edited the question and fiddle to hopefully clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way the data is being bound to the rects is incorrect:

```
var levels = levelsHolder.selectAll('rect.square-levels')
.data(data[key])
```

results in assigning `data["Object one"]`, then `data["Object two"]` and so on which enters `rects` for just `data["Object one"]` in the first iteration i.e. 3 rects and as there's no **update** method used, the `rects` stay as they are resulting in 3 rectangles corresponding to the `data["Object one"]` array elements.

A solution would be to use the `data`'s **keys** and map the array's first elements as follows:

```
var levels = levelsHolder.selectAll('rect.square-levels')
.data(Object.keys(data).map(function(k) { return data[k][0]; }))
```

Now, I'm being nice and providing you the function for the button click as well (just kidding). Anyway, I'm using two variables "initial" and "max" which goes from 0 through maximum array length in the data and accordingly changes the bound data to the rects. And yes, it can be done using underscore.js as well but I didn't find the need of it here.

**Button on click:**

```
d3.select('#myButton').on('click', function() {
   initial++;
   if(initial > max) { initial = 0; }
   levels.data(Object.keys(data).map(function(k) { return data[k][initial]; }));

   drawSquares();
});
```

**Here's a code snippet using the above logic (its not the best of logics but you can change it as per your requirements):**

```js
var data= {
 "Object one":[
  {"date":"2010",
   "value":"80",},
  {"date":"2011",
   "value":"94",},
  {"date":"2012",
   "value":"50",},
 ],
   "Object two":[
  {"date":"2010",
   "value":"104",},
  {"date":"2011",
   "value":"41",},
  {"date":"2012",
   "value":"92",},
 ],
   "Object three":[
  {"date":"2010",
   "value":"75",},
  {"date":"2011",
   "value":"43",},
  {"date":"2012",
   "value":"85",},
 ],
   "Object four":[
  {"date":"2010",
   "value":"75",},
  {"date":"2011",
   "value":"43",},
  {"date":"2012",
   "value":"85",},
 ]
}


  var margin = {top: 30, right: -3, bottom: 30, left:0},
  width = parseInt(d3.select('#holder').style('width'),10)
  width = width - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = width/2;
  
  var initial = 0, max = data['Object one'].length-1;

  var mainChartSVG = d3.select('#holder')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height)

  var frameHolder = mainChartSVG.append('g')
    .classed('holder-frames',true);

  // Draw squares to show levels

  var maxValue = d3.max(data, function(d){
    return d.value;
  });

  var valueScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0,100])
    .range([50,0]);

  var levelsHolder = mainChartSVG.append('g')
    .classed('holder-levels',true);
    
  var levels = levelsHolder.selectAll('rect.square-levels')
    .data(Object.keys(data).map(function(k) { return data[k][initial]; }))
    .enter().append('rect')
    .classed('square-levels', true);
    
 function drawSquares() {
      levels
        .attr({
          x: function(d, i){
             return i % 5 * width/5
          },
          y: function(d, i){
             return valueScale(d.value)+(Math.floor(i / 5) * width/5)
          },
        width: width/5-3,
        height: function(d) {
          return (width/5-3)-valueScale(d.value) ;
        },
        fill:"red",
        class: function(d) { return d.value; }
    })
}
drawSquares();

var frameHolder = mainChartSVG.append('g')
    .classed('holder-frames',true);

  var keyarray = Object.keys(data)

  var frames = frameHolder.selectAll('rect.square-frame')
    .data(keyarray)
    .enter().append('rect')
    .classed('square-frame', true)
    .attr({
      x:function(d, i){
        //console.log(d, "D VALUE")
        return i % 5 * (width/5 )
      },
      y:function(d, i){
        return Math.floor(i / 5) * (width/5 )
      },
      width: width/5-3,
      height: width/5-3,
    })

d3.select('#myButton').on('click', function() {
 initial++;
  if(initial > max) { initial = 0; }
  levels.data(Object.keys(data).map(function(k) { return data[k][initial]; }));
  
 drawSquares();
});
```

```css
body{
  background-color:white;
}

.square-frame{
  stroke: #38434f;
  fill: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px 8px;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: gray;
  color: black;
}

#myButton {
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="myButton">&#8250;</a>
<div id="holder"></div>
```

Hope this helps. Let me know if you come across any questions.